# Setting a widget input using a variable in Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, widget, databricks

Like the question says, I want to know if/how you can set a Databricks widget input using a variable instead of a hard-coded value. I have two notebooks. One needs apply a filter to some values. The other needs to run some code, then optionally (as dictated by another widget) apply that same filter.
Here's some example code (modified for simplicity/privacy).

In Notebook2 we have:

```
start = dbutils.widgets.get("startDate")
filter_condition = None
if start:
  filter_condition = f"GeneratedDate >= '{start}'"

foo = important_function(filter_condition)
```

```
%run ./Notebook1 $run_training="True" $num_trials=100 $filter_string=filter_condition
```

where I want `filter_condition` to be the above-defined variable and not a string.

In Notebook1, there's some code like:

```
if run_training=="True":
  bar = optimize_model(datasets, grid, int(num_trials))
elif run_training=="False":
  baz = apply_filter(filter_string)
else:
  # Throw error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the notebook.run function of the [databricks utilities](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html) package, rather than the %run command:

```
dbutils.notebook.run(path='./Notebook1', 
                     timeout_seconds=300,
                     arguments={'run_training':'True',
                                'num_trials':100,
                                'filter_string':filter_condition})
```

The notebook will be run as a "[ephemeral](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html)" job. Note that the notebook will run in a separate notebook environment, so any variables etc created will not be brought back into the notebook you ran it from. Your input arguments come through as widget variables, which can be accessed using:

```
num_trails = dbutils.widgets.get('num_trails')
```

etc. I think you are already doing that though.